# Could not get the output.. The parameter given in the function is not read

Tags: javascript

I tried to make a program that could return the dates, if the total of the date is matching find variable.The date 01/08/1996 gives a total of = 34 ..(i.e) 0+1+0+8+1+9+9+6 = 34; Please show me where I've gone wrong.

```js
    var find = 25;

    for (var year = 2010 ; year <= 2019 ; year++){
        for (var month = 1 ; month <=12 ; month++){
            var dateLength;
            switch(true){
                case (month === 1 ||month === 3 ||month === 5 || month ===7|| month ===8||month ===10 || month ===12 ):
                    dateLength = 31;
                    break;
                case (month === 2 && year%4 ===0):
                    dateLength = 29;
                    break;
                case (month === 2 && year%4 !==0 ):
                    dateLength = 28;
                    break;
                default: 
                    dateLength = 30;
            }
            for (var day = 1 ; day <= dateLength; day ++){
                dayFunction(day)
                monthFunction(month)
                yearFunction(year)
                finalTotalFunction(finalDayTotal,finalMonthTotal,finalYearTotal)
                if (GrandTotal === find){
                 console.log(day,"/",month,"/",year)
                 }
            }
        }
    }
    var finalDayTotal =0;
    var finalMonthTotal =0;
    var finalYearTotal =0;
    var GrandTotal;

    var dayFunction = (day) =>{
        daySplitter=day.toString().split("");
        var split =daySplitter.map(Number)
        for (let n of split){
            finalDayTotal += n;
        }
    }
    var monthFunction = (month) =>{
        monthSplitter=month.toString().split("");
        var split =monthSplitter.map(Number)
        for (let n of split){
            finalMonthTotal += n;
        }
    }
    var yearFunction = (year) =>{
        yearSplitter=year.toString().split("");
        var split =yearSplitter.map(Number)
        for (let n of split){
            finalYearTotal += n;
        }
        
    }
    function finalTotalFunction(fd,fm,fy){
        GrandTotal = fd+fm+fy;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    var finalDayTotal =0;
    var finalMonthTotal =0;
    var finalYearTotal =0;
    var GrandTotal;
    
    var dayFunction = (day) =>{
     finalDayTotal = 0
        daySplitter=day.toString().split("");
        var split =daySplitter.map(Number)
        for (let n of split){
            finalDayTotal += n;
        }
    }
    var monthFunction = (month) =>{
     finalMonthTotal = 0
        monthSplitter=month.toString().split("");
        var split =monthSplitter.map(Number)
        for (let n of split){
            finalMonthTotal += n;
        }
    }
    var yearFunction = (year) =>{
     finalYearTotal = 0
        yearSplitter=year.toString().split("");
        var split =yearSplitter.map(Number)
        for (let n of split){
            finalYearTotal += n;
        }
        
    }
    function finalTotalFunction(fd,fm,fy){
        GrandTotal = fd+fm+fy;
    }
    
    var find = 25;
    
    for (var year = 2010 ; year <= 2019 ; year++){
        for (var month = 1 ; month <=12 ; month++){
            var dateLength;
            switch(true){
                case (month === 1 ||month === 3 ||month === 5 || month ===7|| month ===8||month ===10 || month ===12 ):
                    dateLength = 31;
                    break;
                case (month === 2 && year%4 ===0):
                    dateLength = 29;
                    break;
                case (month === 2 && year%4 !==0 ):
                    dateLength = 28;
                    break;
                default: 
                    dateLength = 30;
            }
            for (var day = 1 ; day <= dateLength; day ++){
                dayFunction(day)
                monthFunction(month)
                yearFunction(year)
                finalTotalFunction(finalDayTotal,finalMonthTotal,finalYearTotal)
                if (GrandTotal === find){
                 console.log(day,"/",month,"/",year)
                 }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot .  This happened to be my first JS program and I was struggling with this from morning

Answer (score 0):

`dayFunction`, `monthFunction` and `yearFunction` aren't being hoisted. If you use `function foo() { }` syntax though, they will work. However, you should avoid mixing modern js with archaic syntax if you can.

Your code can also be simplified (if I understand what you're trying to achieve):

```js
const date = "01/08/1996";

const isDateSumMatching = (date, value) => {
  return date
    .split("")
    .filter((e) => /\d/.test(e))
    .reduce((sum, current) => sum + Number(current), 0)
    === value;
};

console.log(isDateSumMatching(date, 25));
console.log(isDateSumMatching(date, 34));
```